# MySQL RAND() not working, always getting same result

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I have this MySQL query :

```
while ($x <= 9) {
   $data_1 = "SELECT scene FROM star WHERE star LIKE '%".$star."%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT  1";
   $result_1 = mysql_query ($data_1) OR die("Error: $data_1 </br>".mysql_error());

   while($row_1 = mysql_fetch_object($result_1)) {
      $scene = $row_1->scene;
      $x = $x + 1;
   }
}
```

I want to get everytime a new scene for each execution, but I always get the same scene. Whats the issue? Can someone make me a few pointers in which direction I have to search ?

Comment: Instead of running _9_ queries just do `limit 9` when you get it straightened out.  Looks like you're overwriting `$scene` each time too and that should be an array.  Stop using `mysql_*` calls and checkout [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo).

Comment: do your like conditions when used actually return more than 1 row? We don't know the contents of your table, so we can't tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is tie a random seed to each row, and tie a new one each time. Do this by assigning a random value as an aliased transient column to your table, and *then* select from it.

```
SELECT s.scene as scene FROM (
    SELECT stars.scene as scene, RAND() as seed 
      FROM stars
     WHERE star LIKE '%".$star."%' 
  ORDER BY seed
) s
LIMIT  1;
```

Using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) it's going to look something like this:

```
function getScene() {
    $sql = 'SELECT s.scene as scene FROM ( SELECT stars.scene as scene, RAND() as seed FROM stars WHERE star LIKE '%:star%' ORDER BY seed ) s LIMIT  1;';
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);//'db' is the PDO connection
    $query->execute(array(':star' => "Allison Brie"));

    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['scene'] . "\t";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with the rest of your code, but it mostly looks like cruft.

Comment: "seed" usually refers to a number you feed into a random number generator, not to the numbers it produces. I'm not saying your answer is incorrect, but the name may be misleading.

Comment: mh with your code I get "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @octem I see your point, but I'm not sure it's far enough off the meaning of seed to matter. Think seeding a basketball tournament.

Comment: @Johnny187 I have updated the response to fix one typo and the alias issue.

Comment: Mh it's the same issue with your code, same scene every time. I think I have to go for the error arron mentioned that I'm overwriting it. Thanks for the pointer guys !